# Bootstrap CSS z-index

Tags: css, laravel-livewire

I am trying to place a div on top of the other. I read through different answers to the questions on this site. But none of them worked for me. I want the search results ('Anton') to appear on top of the table ('Customer').

Below is my code fragment related to the search text box and the results div. (FYI: I am using Laravel LiveWire)

```html
<div class="relative pb-2">
    <input 
        type="text" 
        name="model-search" 
        wire:model="query"
        wire:keydown.escape="clear"
        wire:keydown.tab="clear"
        placeholder="enter search text here..."
        class="form-control form-control-sm search-box" 
    >
    @if(!empty($query))
        <div class="absolute shadow-sm rounded-sm mt-2" style="z-index: 1000 !important;">
            @if(!empty($models))
                @foreach ($models as $model)
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action py-1">{{$model['name']}}</a>
                @endforeach
            @else
                <div class="list-group-item py-1">No results</div>
            @endif
        </div>
    @endif
</div>
```

*Update 1*

- Attached screenshot of the code segment of the blade file where the livewire component is used.

[image: Blade file]

- Result

[image: Result]

- CSS

  .search-results {
      z-index: 1000 !important;
  }

Comment: Can you share the CSS?

Comment: @martinho I updated the question. Please check